# How to get the top 10 largest rows in a table based on the length of a BLOB column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:

```
table name: creditCardTranactions
columns: CardNumber (varchar), Picture (PDF BLOB)
the table contains over 500 million records
```

I would like to find a query which would display the top 10 or top 20 cards which have the largest picture (based on the length of the BLOB).

I have tried to find this on this site but nothing pointing to this particular scenario.

So For example the data could look like this:

```
CardNumber|PDFLength(length of blob)

9126742104827074|2000
7582719459129949|10000
7582719459129949|200000
7582719459129949|5000
7582719459129949|2000
2228624568281341|100000
1349721467976156|1000000
3259332536233670|50000
2773392693004739|25000
0689192068212049|500
```

so if i would like the top 2 it would result in showing me

```
1349721467976156|1000000
7582719459129949|200000
```

(notice that we need to get rid of the duplicate with same card number but lower length)

I was trying to use the rank or dense_rank functions but without success as the duplicates are showing.

Can anyone shed some light?

Many thanks

Comment: Why on earth do you have a credit card transactions table with 500 million rows and store a picture in PDF format *for every single row* ?

Comment: this just a way for me to describe easily the scenario but it is not real structure I have described here. the real scenario has nothing to do with credit cards of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly ...

```
SELECT ROWNUM, CARDNUMBER, PDFLENGTH
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    CARDNUMBER, MAX(PDFLENGTH) AS PDFLENGTH
  FROM
    creditCardTranactions
  GROUP BY 
    CARDNUMBER
  ORDER BY 2 desc
  )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99d04/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one. It does do the job thanks to the MAX function.

Comment: Hi, many thanks this answered the question with the max function and group by. Would you have any recommendation how to speed up this query? As I said our data is huge and 5 minutes of data in the where clause results in over 10 minutes query :-(

Comment: Do you have indexes on `CARDNUMBER` & `PDFLENGTH` ?